# Can't convert .ts files that downloaded from .m3u8 file to mp4

Tags: python, ffmpeg, blob, m3u8

I Have This Files:

```
001.ts  014.ts  027.ts  040.ts  053.ts  066.ts  079.ts  092.ts  105.ts  118.ts  131.ts  144.ts  157.ts  170.ts  183.ts  196.ts  209.ts  222.ts  235.ts  248.ts  261.ts  274.ts  287.ts  300.ts  313.ts  326.ts
002.ts  015.ts  028.ts  041.ts  054.ts  067.ts  080.ts  093.ts  106.ts  119.ts  132.ts  145.ts  158.ts  171.ts  184.ts  197.ts  210.ts  223.ts  236.ts  249.ts  262.ts  275.ts  288.ts  301.ts  314.ts  327.ts
003.ts  016.ts  029.ts  042.ts  055.ts  068.ts  081.ts  094.ts  107.ts  120.ts  133.ts  146.ts  159.ts  172.ts  185.ts  198.ts  211.ts  224.ts  237.ts  250.ts  263.ts  276.ts  289.ts  302.ts  315.ts  328.ts
004.ts  017.ts  030.ts  043.ts  056.ts  069.ts  082.ts  095.ts  108.ts  121.ts  134.ts  147.ts  160.ts  173.ts  186.ts  199.ts  212.ts  225.ts  238.ts  251.ts  264.ts  277.ts  290.ts  303.ts  316.ts  329.ts
005.ts  018.ts  031.ts  044.ts  057.ts  070.ts  083.ts  096.ts  109.ts  122.ts  135.ts  148.ts  161.ts  174.ts  187.ts  200.ts  213.ts  226.ts  239.ts  252.ts  265.ts  278.ts  291.ts  304.ts  317.ts  330.ts
006.ts  019.ts  032.ts  045.ts  058.ts  071.ts  084.ts  097.ts  110.ts  123.ts  136.ts  149.ts  162.ts  175.ts  188.ts  201.ts  214.ts  227.ts  240.ts  253.ts  266.ts  279.ts  292.ts  305.ts  318.ts  331.ts
007.ts  020.ts  033.ts  046.ts  059.ts  072.ts  085.ts  098.ts  111.ts  124.ts  137.ts  150.ts  163.ts  176.ts  189.ts  202.ts  215.ts  228.ts  241.ts  254.ts  267.ts  280.ts  293.ts  306.ts  319.ts  332.ts
008.ts  021.ts  034.ts  047.ts  060.ts  073.ts  086.ts  099.ts  112.ts  125.ts  138.ts  151.ts  164.ts  177.ts  190.ts  203.ts  216.ts  229.ts  242.ts  255.ts  268.ts  281.ts  294.ts  307.ts  320.ts  333.ts
009.ts  022.ts  035.ts  048.ts  061.ts  074.ts  087.ts  100.ts  113.ts  126.ts  139.ts  152.ts  165.ts  178.ts  191.ts  204.ts  217.ts  230.ts  243.ts  256.ts  269.ts  282.ts  295.ts  308.ts  321.ts  334.ts
010.ts  023.ts  036.ts  049.ts  062.ts  075.ts  088.ts  101.ts  114.ts  127.ts  140.ts  153.ts  166.ts  179.ts  192.ts  205.ts  218.ts  231.ts  244.ts  257.ts  270.ts  283.ts  296.ts  309.ts  322.ts
011.ts  024.ts  037.ts  050.ts  063.ts  076.ts  089.ts  102.ts  115.ts  128.ts  141.ts  154.ts  167.ts  180.ts  193.ts  206.ts  219.ts  232.ts  245.ts  258.ts  271.ts  284.ts  297.ts  310.ts  323.ts
012.ts  025.ts  038.ts  051.ts  064.ts  077.ts  090.ts  103.ts  116.ts  129.ts  142.ts  155.ts  168.ts  181.ts  194.ts  207.ts  220.ts  233.ts  246.ts  259.ts  272.ts  285.ts  298.ts  311.ts  324.ts
013.ts  026.ts  039.ts  052.ts  065.ts  078.ts  091.ts  104.ts  117.ts  130.ts  143.ts  156.ts  169.ts  182.ts  195.ts  208.ts  221.ts  234.ts  247.ts  260.ts  273.ts  286.ts  299.ts  312.ts  325.ts
```

That I Downloaded With This Python Program (m3u8 File Does Not Work!):

```
import requests
import shutil
import os
import subprocess


def strip_end(text, suffix):
    if not text.endswith(suffix):
        return text
    return text[:len(text)-len(suffix)]


def download_file(url):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    command = f"wget -O {cwd}/ts_files/{url.split('/')[-1]} {url}"
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)


base_url = "https://stream.example.com/video/2021/example/720p_{}.ts"

if not os.path.exists('ts_files'):
    print('ts_file folder is not found, creating the folder.')
    os.makedirs('ts_files')

i = 1
while True:
    if len(str(i)) == 1:
        num = f"00{i}"
    elif len(str(i)) == 2:
        num = f"0{i}"
    else:
        num = str(i)
    url = base_url.replace("{}", num)
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    print(f'downloading {i}')
    if r.status_code != 404:
        download_file(url)  # comment out this line to download ts files.
    else:
        print("404")
        break
    i = i+1

cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
TS_DIR = 'ts_files'
with open('merged.ts', 'wb') as merged:
    for ts_file in os.listdir(f'{cwd}/{TS_DIR}'):
        with open(f'{cwd}/{TS_DIR}/{ts_file}', 'rb') as mergefile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(mergefile, merged)
```

My Problem Is When I Want To Convert All This Files To One .ts File And Then An MP4 File With ffmpeg, I Get An Error:

```
nima@funlife:~/ts_files$ cat ./*.ts > all.ts
nima@funlife:~/ts_files$ ffmpeg -i all.ts -acodec copy -vcodec copy all.mp4
ffmpeg version 5.0.1-3+b1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Debian 11.3.0-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=3+b1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
all.ts: Invalid data found when processing input
```

.ts Files Content Is Like This:

```
 }��,.g���}��
             �����c����Ww�c���c���eo��m�����ŧ�  䱉
�b(+��D�FG�zPe��7�&#bz�1ɶ���                      C
�`,��>Ϲc4J��̀��T�I}�"��ކ�R�1��w͋�   "� <�#B`ƪ�̸�co
                                             �9���+��W�
P���N���w��T\5g��
\�E�N�E�v��͑4f��U�@]�ΩX�U�x�E��bwm=ְ�iA�����p���M�����\=�_�I3C�hL�h����0)�ο��*��`���eZ� �ؗ4To�0V��S,�+�>�8_]�W�lNJD�|7e�2s�1X)̃5�0h�������~8ߩg���?e��EK�>۷�L
             ��:6|������>\  �N�WW��,�w
bk��1?*��/��/�5��k����~��                 Lޕ}�a���2�{��l��$�d=����g�{a2��L�����
                         jҫַ��ʿ�"1`ZZ.he)�=�x��E_4:Vg�����H=���x1�����}��W::y�
```

Are They Encrypted Or Something?
I'm Trying To Do This Works With Debian 11.3.0-4, Python 3.10.5

Edit: Thanks Johnny, I Saw This Post: [How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg)
I Tried But I Get An Error Again!

```
nima@funlife:~/ts_files$ ffmpeg -f concat -i file.txt -c copy output.ts
ffmpeg version 5.0.1-3+b1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Debian 11.3.0-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=3+b1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
[concat @ 0x55932dbf2500] Impossible to open '001.ts'
file.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Same Error With ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i file.txt -c copy output.ts

file.txt is The List Of Files!

Comment: Your question is already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg
Don't do that: cat ./*.ts > all.ts

Comment: For kind of "sanity check", you may create synthetic video segments using shell command: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=100 -vcodec libx264 -g 10 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list list.txt -segment_list_type ffconcat %03d.ts`. Then concatenate and convert to MP4: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: It Worked! But I Don't Know It's Not Working With My Files!

Comment: Could you post the .m3u8 file?

Comment: I don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

1. .ts file is not a plain text file, so you can’t see anything when open it with vim.
2. You can check the m3u8 file, if there is a license url, if yes, the .ts is encrypted. Also you can try to open the ts file with a media player, like VLC, it is playable if not encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i downloaded.m3u8 -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy Output.mp4
```

If u can get the m3u8 file by:

1. Trying to find it again through the url (if u have it) by replacing`001.ts` to `index.m3u8`
   E.g.(`https://stream.example.com/video/2021/example/index.m3u8`)
2. Make your own m3u8 file:
   An example of an m3u8 file:

   ```
   #EXTM3U
   #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:13
   #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
   #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
   #EXT-X-VERSION:3
   #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
   #EXTINF:4.171,
   seg-1-v1-a1.ts
   #EXTINF:3.295,
   seg-2-v1-a1.ts
   #EXTINF:2.211,
   seg-3-v1-a1.ts
   #EXTINF:6.006,
   seg-4-v1-a1.ts
   ...
   #EXT-X-ENDLIST
   ```

   The numbers after `#EXTINF:` is basically the length of the `.ts` file in seconds. 
   The numbers after `EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` specifies a maximum duration for the segments in the playlist. The actual duration specified by EXTINF may be less so change this value if necessary. 
   Thus, a very simple script can be written.

   1. Move all of your `.ts` files to a folder
   2. Make a `.py` file and try this:

   ```py
   import os
   import subprocess
   m3u8File = """#EXTM3U
   #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:13
   #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
   #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
   #EXT-X-VERSION:3
   #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
   """
   tsPath = "./tsFiles"
   tsFiles = next(os.walk(tsPath), (None, None, []))[2]
   for ts in tsFiles:
       length = subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i', ts, '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv="p=0"'])
       m3u8File += "#EXTINF:"+length+",\n"
       m3u8File += ts + "\n"
   m3u8File += "#EXT-X-ENDLIST"
   with open("output.m3u8",'wb') as output:
       output.write(m3u8File)
       output.close()
   ```

   I haven't tested the code above, but I trust that you will be able to debug it yourself, also I've never used `subprocess.checkOutput()` before so I'm not sure if it will run properly. But anyway, make sure you have ffmpeg binary folder added to `Path` environmental variable, otherwise the `ffprobe` command won't work. `ffprobe` should come with `ffmpeg`.
   Let me know if it works along with the error message if it doesn't.

Please Accept this answer if it helped you. Thanks!
References:

1. [Live playlist, must #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION and #EXTINF be equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351692/live-playlist-must-ext-x-targetduration-and-extinf-be-equal)
2. [How to extract duration time from ffmpeg output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239350/how-to-extract-duration-time-from-ffmpeg-output)
3. [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)
4. [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Spelling and grammar corrected by Microsoft Editor ;)